# how to select data from existing tables using sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I already have tables in postgresql. I want to retrieve data from them using sequelize. I used several ways to do it. But still can't map the db schma to sequelize in node.js.

```
  const Test = Conn.define('test', {
          race_id: 
          {
           type: Sequelize.STRING,
           allowNull: false   
           },
          race_name:
          {
           type: Sequelize.STRING,
           allowNull: false
          }
   });

  Conn.sync(); 
export default Conn;
```

I define the schema in node.js and have a table with same schema in postgresql.

But when execute `Db.models.test.findAll({ where: args });`

The console will output result as following:

> Executing (default): SELECT "id", "race_id", "race_name", "createdAt",
>   "updatedAt" FROM "tests" AS "test";

And I will get another output that is

```
column \"id\" does not exist
```

I can't figure out why sequelize retrieve data from tests table and it retrieve columns that I don't have.

How could I select table from existing tables using sequelize?
I need to use ORM for requirement and can't use other way to get data.

Answer (score 4):

You should define your primary key :

```
const Test = Conn.define('test', {
      race_id: 
      {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
       allowNull: false,
       primaryKey: true
       },
      race_name:
      {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
       allowNull: false
      }
});
```

This will replace `id` in your query with your primary key.

Check [working with legacy tables](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/advanced/legacy.html#working-with-legacy-tables), since it might help you for future problems.

Comment: @AkshayM fixed.